# Retrieve ssis Package Data from SQL Server

Tags: sql, ssis, sql-server-2014

I am looking forward to extract ssis package data from SQL Server 2014.

I tried searching in `SSISDB.internal.packages`, but there it displays NULL in package_data column.

Could anyone tell me how to get ssis package data from SQL Server 2014?

Answer (score 0):

Use SSDT to import the project from SSISDB. Option A on the following link: http://www.mssqlgirl.com/editing-published-ssis-package-in-sql-server-2012.html

Comment: @user6447731 I'm happy to here that. Please mark it as answered.